# No route matches [POST] "/experiences/index"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie to Rails and have been developing an web application and must have broken something along the way.  When creating a new “Experience”, I am receiving this error 'No route matches [POST] "/experiences/index”’.  I have tried adding “post ‘experiences#index’ which stops the error, but then the experience is not created.

**routes.rb**

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

      mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

      resource :experiences do
        member do
          get 'dashboard'
          get 'index'
          get 'bookings'
        end
      end


      resources :experiences, except: [:edit] do
        member do
          get 'listing'
          get 'pricing'
          get 'description'
          get 'photo_upload'
          get 'amenities'
          get 'location'
          get 'about'
          get 'subcats'
          get 'languages'
          get 'timeslots'
        end
         resources :photos, only: [:create, :destroy]
         resources :timeslots, only: [:create, :destroy]
         resources :reservations, only: [:create]
         resources :calendars
      end

      resources :experiences do
        resources :subcategories
      end

      resources :subcategories do
        resources :experiences
      end

      resources :categories do
        resources :experiences
        resources :subcategories
      end

      devise_for :users, controllers: {
          sessions: 'users/sessions',
          passwords: 'users/passwords',
          registrations: 'users/registrations'
      }

      namespace :admin do
        get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
      end

      resources :host_requests do
        resources :users
      end

      resources :static_pages do
        resources :users
      end

      resources :users, only: [:show]

      get '/host_calendar' => "calendars#host"

      get 'search' => 'static_pages#search'


      root to: "static_pages#home"

      # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    end
```

**experiences_controller.rb**

```
    class ExperiencesController < ApplicationController

      before_action :set_experience, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :listing, :pricing, :description, :photo_upload, :amenities, :location, :subcats, :languages, :about, :timeslots]

      before_action :set_subcategories, only: [:subcats]

      before_action :set_languages, only: [:languages]

      before_action :set_amenities, only: [:amenities]

      before_action :is_authorised, except: [:show, :index, :new, :create, :dashboard, :bookings]

      before_action :authenticate_user!

      load_and_authorize_resource

      # GET /experiences
      # GET /experiences.json
      def index
        if current_user.admin_role?
          redirect_to admin_url
        elsif current_user.host_role?
          @experiences = current_user.experiences
        else
          @experiences = Experience.published
        end
      end

      def dashboard
        if current_user.admin_role?
          redirect_to admin_url
        elsif current_user.host_role?
          @experiences = current_user.experiences
        else
          redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission.  Apply to be a host!"
        end
      end

      # GET /experiences/1
      # GET /experiences/1.json
      def show

        if current_user.user_role?
          if !@experience.published?
            redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission."
          end
        end

        @base_latitude = @experience.latitude
        @base_longitude = @experience.longitude

        @base_timezone = Timezone.lookup(@base_latitude, @base_longitude)
        @timezone_name = @base_timezone.name
      end

      # GET /experiences/new
      def new
        @experience = current_user.experiences.new
        @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
        @subcategories = Subcategory.all
        @languages = Language.all
        @amenities = Amenity.all
      end

      # GET /experiences/1/edit
      def edit
        @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
        @languages = Language.all
        @amenities = Amenity.all
        @experience.subcategory_ids = params[:subcategory_ids]
        @experience.language_ids = params[:language_ids]
        @experience.amenity_ids = params[:amenity_ids]
        redirect_to listing_experience_path(@experience)

      end

      # POST /experiences
      # POST /experiences.json
      def create
        @experience = current_user.experiences.build(experience_params)
        @experience.subcategory_ids = params[:subcategory_ids]
        @experience.language_ids = params[:language_ids]
        @experience.amenity_ids = params[:amenity_ids]

        if @experience.save
          redirect_to listing_experience_path(@experience), notice: "Saved..."
        else
          render :new, notice: "Something went wrong..."
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /experiences/1
      # PATCH/PUT /experiences/1.json
      def update

        new_params = experience_params
        new_params = experience_params.merge(active: true) if is_ready_experience

        if @experience.update(new_params)
          flash[:notice] = "Updated..."
        else
          flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong..."
        end

        redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
      end

      # DELETE /experiences/1
      # DELETE /experiences/1.json
      def destroy
        @experience.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to experiences_url, notice: 'Experience was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end

        def listing
        end

        def pricing
        end

        def description
        end

        def about
        end

        def photo_upload
          @photos = @experience.photos
        end

        def amenities
          @experience.amenity_ids = params[:amenity_ids]
        end

        def subcats
          @experience.subcategory_ids = params[:subcategory_ids]

        end

        def languages
          @experience.language_ids = params[:language_ids]
        end

        def timeslots

        end

        def location
        end

        def bookings
          if current_user.admin_role?
            redirect_to admin_url
          elsif current_user.host_role?
            @experiences = current_user.experiences.published
          else
            redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission.  Apply to be a host!"
          end
        end



      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_experience
          @experience = Experience.find(params[:id])
          @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
          @photos = @experience.photos
        end

        def is_authorised
          redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission" unless current_user.id == @experience.user_id
        end

        def set_subcategories
          @subcategories =  Subcategory.all
        end

        def set_languages
          @languages = Language.all
        end

        def set_amenities
          @amenities = Amenity.all
        end

        def is_ready_experience
          !@experience.active && !@experience.name.blank? && !@experience.summary.blank? && !@experience.what_do.blank? && !@experience.host_bring.blank? && !@experience.location.blank? && !@experience.price.blank? && !@experience.length.blank? && !@experience.accomodate.blank? && !@experience.notracetip.blank? && !@experience.difficulty.blank? && !@experience.cat_help.blank? && !@experience.subcategories.blank? && !@experience.languages.blank? && !@experience.amenities.blank? && !@experience.photos.blank? && !@experience.user_bring.blank? && !@experience.what_learn.blank? && !@experience.about_guide.blank?

        end

        def has_inventory
          @experience.timeslot.inventory > 0
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def experience_params
          params.require(:experience).permit(:name, :summary, :about_guide, :what_do, :host_bring, :user_bring, :what_learn,
            :location, :price, :length, :difficulty, :cat_help, :accomodate, :notracetip, :subcategory_ids => [], :language_ids => [], :amenity_ids => [])
        end
    end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <h1 class="text-center">Create Your Experience</h1>
        <div class="container">
          <%= form_for @experience do |f| %>


          <!-- Experience Name // Text Field -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Experience Name</label>
              <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name of your experience", class: "form-control", required: true %>
            </div>
          </div>

            <!-- Experience Description // Text Area -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Experience Description</label>
                <%= f.text_area :summary, rows: 5, placeholder: "Describe your experience", class: "form-control", required: true %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Location // Text Field -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Location</label>
                <%= f.text_field :location, placeholder: "Where is your experience?", class: "form-control", required: true %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Length of Trip // Dropdown Select -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="select">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Category Type</label> <br/>
                  <%= f.select :cat_help, [["Activity", 1], ["Food & Beverage", 2], ["Vista Point", 3]],
                                id: "cat_help", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control", required: true %>
                </div>
              </div>

            <!-- Length of Trip // Dropdown Select -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 select">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Length Type</label> <br/>
                  <%= f.select :length, [["Daytrip", "Daytrip"], ["Overnight", "Overnight"], ["Weekend Getaway", "Weekend"], ["Multi-Day", "Multi-Day"]],
                                id: "length", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control", required: true %>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Difficulty Rating // Dropdown Select -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 select">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Difficulty</label> <br/>
                    <%= f.select :difficulty, [["Light", "Light"], ["Moderate", "Moderate"], ["Advanced", "Advanced"], ["Extreme", "Extreme"]],
                                  id: "difficulty", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control", required: true %>
                  </div>
                </div>


              <!-- Group Size // Dropdown Select -->
              <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 select">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Group Size</label> <br/>
                  <%= f.select :accomodate, [["1", 1], ["2-4", 2], ["5-8", 3], ["8+", 4]],
                                id: "accomodate", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control", required: true %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


      <!-- Final Submit // Button -->

      <div>
        <%= f.submit "Create Your Experience", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block" %>
      </div>

    <% end %>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Output from Rails Routes - Updated with new Routes**

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                   Controller#Action
            bookings_experience GET    /experiences/:id/bookings(.:format)                           experiences#bookings
           dashboard_experience GET    /experiences/:id/dashboard(.:format)                          experiences#dashboard
             listing_experience GET    /experiences/:id/listing(.:format)                            experiences#listing
             pricing_experience GET    /experiences/:id/pricing(.:format)                            experiences#pricing
         description_experience GET    /experiences/:id/description(.:format)                        experiences#description
        photo_upload_experience GET    /experiences/:id/photo_upload(.:format)                       experiences#photo_upload
           amenities_experience GET    /experiences/:id/amenities(.:format)                          experiences#amenities
            location_experience GET    /experiences/:id/location(.:format)                           experiences#location
               about_experience GET    /experiences/:id/about(.:format)                              experiences#about
             subcats_experience GET    /experiences/:id/subcats(.:format)                            experiences#subcats
           languages_experience GET    /experiences/:id/languages(.:format)                          experiences#languages
           timeslots_experience GET    /experiences/:id/timeslots(.:format)                          experiences#timeslots
              experience_photos POST   /experiences/:experience_id/photos(.:format)                  photos#create
               experience_photo DELETE /experiences/:experience_id/photos/:id(.:format)              photos#destroy
           experience_timeslots POST   /experiences/:experience_id/timeslots(.:format)               timeslots#create
            experience_timeslot DELETE /experiences/:experience_id/timeslots/:id(.:format)           timeslots#destroy
        experience_reservations POST   /experiences/:experience_id/reservations(.:format)            reservations#create
           experience_calendars GET    /experiences/:experience_id/calendars(.:format)               calendars#index
                                POST   /experiences/:experience_id/calendars(.:format)               calendars#create
        new_experience_calendar GET    /experiences/:experience_id/calendars/new(.:format)           calendars#new
       edit_experience_calendar GET    /experiences/:experience_id/calendars/:id/edit(.:format)      calendars#edit
            experience_calendar GET    /experiences/:experience_id/calendars/:id(.:format)           calendars#show
                                PATCH  /experiences/:experience_id/calendars/:id(.:format)           calendars#update
                                PUT    /experiences/:experience_id/calendars/:id(.:format)           calendars#update
                                DELETE /experiences/:experience_id/calendars/:id(.:format)           calendars#destroy
       experience_subcategories GET    /experiences/:experience_id/subcategories(.:format)           subcategories#index
                                POST   /experiences/:experience_id/subcategories(.:format)           subcategories#create
     new_experience_subcategory GET    /experiences/:experience_id/subcategories/new(.:format)       subcategories#new
    edit_experience_subcategory GET    /experiences/:experience_id/subcategories/:id/edit(.:format)  subcategories#edit
         experience_subcategory GET    /experiences/:experience_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)       subcategories#show
                                PATCH  /experiences/:experience_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)       subcategories#update
                                PUT    /experiences/:experience_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)       subcategories#update
                                DELETE /experiences/:experience_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)       subcategories#destroy
                    experiences GET    /experiences(.:format)                                        experiences#index
                                POST   /experiences(.:format)                                        experiences#create
                 new_experience GET    /experiences/new(.:format)                                    experiences#new
                edit_experience GET    /experiences/:id/edit(.:format)                               experiences#edit
                     experience GET    /experiences/:id(.:format)                                    experiences#show
                                PATCH  /experiences/:id(.:format)                                    experiences#update
                                PUT    /experiences/:id(.:format)                                    experiences#update
                                DELETE /experiences/:id(.:format)                                    experiences#destroy
        subcategory_experiences GET    /subcategories/:subcategory_id/experiences(.:format)          experiences#index
                                POST   /subcategories/:subcategory_id/experiences(.:format)          experiences#create
     new_subcategory_experience GET    /subcategories/:subcategory_id/experiences/new(.:format)      experiences#new
    edit_subcategory_experience GET    /subcategories/:subcategory_id/experiences/:id/edit(.:format) experiences#edit
         subcategory_experience GET    /subcategories/:subcategory_id/experiences/:id(.:format)      experiences#show
                                PATCH  /subcategories/:subcategory_id/experiences/:id(.:format)      experiences#update
                                PUT    /subcategories/:subcategory_id/experiences/:id(.:format)      experiences#update
                                DELETE /subcategories/:subcategory_id/experiences/:id(.:format)      experiences#destroy
                  subcategories GET    /subcategories(.:format)                                      subcategories#index
                                POST   /subcategories(.:format)                                      subcategories#create
                new_subcategory GET    /subcategories/new(.:format)                                  subcategories#new
               edit_subcategory GET    /subcategories/:id/edit(.:format)                             subcategories#edit
                    subcategory GET    /subcategories/:id(.:format)                                  subcategories#show
                                PATCH  /subcategories/:id(.:format)                                  subcategories#update
                                PUT    /subcategories/:id(.:format)                                  subcategories#update
                                DELETE /subcategories/:id(.:format)                                  subcategories#destroy
           category_experiences GET    /categories/:category_id/experiences(.:format)                experiences#index
                                POST   /categories/:category_id/experiences(.:format)                experiences#create
        new_category_experience GET    /categories/:category_id/experiences/new(.:format)            experiences#new
       edit_category_experience GET    /categories/:category_id/experiences/:id/edit(.:format)       experiences#edit
            category_experience GET    /categories/:category_id/experiences/:id(.:format)            experiences#show
                                PATCH  /categories/:category_id/experiences/:id(.:format)            experiences#update
                                PUT    /categories/:category_id/experiences/:id(.:format)            experiences#update
                                DELETE /categories/:category_id/experiences/:id(.:format)            experiences#destroy
         category_subcategories GET    /categories/:category_id/subcategories(.:format)              subcategories#index
                                POST   /categories/:category_id/subcategories(.:format)              subcategories#create
       new_category_subcategory GET    /categories/:category_id/subcategories/new(.:format)          subcategories#new
      edit_category_subcategory GET    /categories/:category_id/subcategories/:id/edit(.:format)     subcategories#edit
           category_subcategory GET    /categories/:category_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)          subcategories#show
                                PATCH  /categories/:category_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)          subcategories#update
                                PUT    /categories/:category_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)          subcategories#update
                                DELETE /categories/:category_id/subcategories/:id(.:format)          subcategories#destroy
                     categories GET    /categories(.:format)                                         categories#index
                                POST   /categories(.:format)                                         categories#create
                   new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                                     categories#new
                  edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                                categories#edit
                       category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                                     categories#show
                                PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                                     categories#update
                                PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                                     categories#update
                                DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                                     categories#destroy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your **_form.html.erb** look like this:

```
      <!-- Experience Name // Text Field -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Experience Name</label>
          <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name of your experience", class: "form-control", required: true %>
        </div>
      </div>

        <!-- Experience Description // Text Area -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Experience Description</label>
            <%= f.text_area :summary, rows: 5, placeholder: "Describe your experience", class: "form-control", required: true %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Location // Text Field -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Location</label>
            <%= f.text_field :location, placeholder: "Where is your experience?", class: "form-control", required: true %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Length of Trip // Dropdown Select -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="select">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Category Type</label> <br/>
              <%= f.select :cat_help, [["Activity", 1], ["Food & Beverage", 2], ["Vista Point", 3]],
                            id: "cat_help", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control", required: true %>
            </div>
          </div>

        <!-- Length of Trip // Dropdown Select -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 select">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Length Type</label> <br/>
              <%= f.select :length, [["Daytrip", "Daytrip"], ["Overnight", "Overnight"], ["Weekend Getaway", "Weekend"], ["Multi-Day", "Multi-Day"]],
                            id: "length", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control", required: true %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Difficulty Rating // Dropdown Select -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 select">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Difficulty</label> <br/>
                <%= f.select :difficulty, [["Light", "Light"], ["Moderate", "Moderate"], ["Advanced", "Advanced"], ["Extreme", "Extreme"]],
                              id: "difficulty", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control", required: true %>
              </div>
            </div>


          <!-- Group Size // Dropdown Select -->
          <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 select">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Group Size</label> <br/>
              <%= f.select :accomodate, [["1", 1], ["2-4", 2], ["5-8", 3], ["8+", 4]],
                            id: "accomodate", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control", required: true %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


  <!-- Final Submit // Button -->

  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Create Your Experience", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block" %>
  </div>
```

Then **new.html.erb** be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <h1 class="text-center">Create Your Experience</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <%= form_for @experience, url: experiences_path, method: :post do |f| %>
          <%= render partial: '/path/to/form', locals: { f: f } %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update your **routes.rb** temporarily to this: and then update your answer with the new rake routes output

```
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

  resources :experiences do
    collection do
      get 'bookings'
      get 'dashboard'

      get 'listing'
      get 'pricing'
      get 'description'
      get 'photo_upload'
      get 'amenities'
      get 'location'
      get 'about'
      get 'subcats'
      get 'languages'
      get 'timeslots'
    end

     resources :photos, only: [:create, :destroy]
     resources :timeslots, only: [:create, :destroy]
     resources :reservations, only: [:create]
     resources :calendars

     resources :subcategories
  end

  resources :subcategories do
    resources :experiences
  end

  resources :categories do
    resources :experiences
    resources :subcategories
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'users/sessions',
      passwords: 'users/passwords',
      registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }

  namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
  end

  resources :host_requests do
    resources :users
  end

  resources :static_pages do
    resources :users
  end

  resources :users, only: [:show]

  get '/host_calendar' => "calendars#host"

  get 'search' => 'static_pages#search'


  root to: "static_pages#home"
```